# Audio Cape rev B on Beaglebone black with kernel 3.18

Tags: audio, linux-kernel, device, beagleboneblack

I'm newbie on Beaglebone black and audio cape, could anyone kindly give me the idea how to install audio cape rev B board on kernel 3.18. Since on kernel 3.8, there is cape manager, while it has been removed since 3.13. For the moment, I really have no idea how to install the board on new kernel. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The cape manager is no longer needed.  Simply write the name of your device overlay (eg, BB-BONE-AUDI-02) to

> /sys/devices/bone*/slots

to add the device.

For example,

> # echo BB-BONE-AUDI-02 > /sys/devices/bone*/slots

Then `cat` that file to make sure your device is listed.  Make sure HDMI has been disabled as well.